# A verb or an idiom for "half believe, half doubt"

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Is there any word or some idiomatic expression that would mean "half believe, half doubt"?

For example,

> Having listened to that weird story, children **half believed it, half doubted**.

Meaning that none of the children fully believed the story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as *idioms* are concerned, it's quite possible to express "half belief, half doubt" about something.

> Do you think it will work out?
>
> I'm **on the fence** about it.
>   I"m **of two minds** about it.

From Merriam-Webster:

> [*on the fence*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fence)
>   : in a position of neutrality or indecision
>
> [*of two minds*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/of%20two%20minds)
>   : not decided or certain about something : having two opinions or ideas about something

---

Or, in a different context:

> How sure are you about the plan?
>
> I think it has a **fifty-fifty** chance of success.
>   I think it could **go either way**.

Also from Merriam-Webster:

> [*fifty-fifty*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fifty-fifty)
>   **2** : half favorable and half unfavorable
>   // a *fifty-fifty* chance
>
> [*go either way*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go%20either%20way)
>   —used to say that either of two possible results is likely to occur and that neither is more likely than the other 
>   // I don't know who's going to win. The game could *go either way*.

Answer (score 1):

The children were dubious, uncertain, unsure or suspicious about the truthfulness or accuracy of the story.

Of course, one cannot half believe, half doubt something.

If you are not certain whether it is true, you simply doubt it.

https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/dubious

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

> The children were **skeptical** about the story.

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/skeptical

Comment: A **skeptik** (or sceptic) is a person who doubts something. It's a noun, not an adjective. The adjective is **skeptical** (**sceptical**) Since a sceptik is a doubter, the answer is misleading. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/skeptic